# How do I import singleton object from Scala package in Java?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to use ARIMA object (Scala), which is imported from [a package](http://sryza.github.io/spark-timeseries/0.3.0/scaladocs/index.html#com.cloudera.sparkts.models.package), in my Java program. Although the compilation succeeds, meaning that ARIMA class is recognized during compilation, there is **NoClassDefFoundError** for the ARIMA object in runtime. ARIMAModel class has no problem with importing since it is a class.

Is there any way to use the Scala object from my Java program?

Here is the source code for the object in Scala package.

File: [.../com/cloudera/sparkts/models/ARIMA.scala](https://github.com/sryza/spark-timeseries/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/sparkts/models/ARIMA.scala)

```
package com.cloudera.sparkts.models

object ARIMA {
    def autoFit(ts: Vector, maxP: Int = 5, maxD: Int = 2, maxQ: Int = 5): ARIMAModel = {
        ...
    }
}

class ARIMAModel(...) {
    ...
}
```

Here is my Java code.

File: src/main/java/SingleSeriesARIMA.java

```
import com.cloudera.sparkts.models.ARIMA;
import com.cloudera.sparkts.models.ARIMAModel;

public class SingleSeriesARIMA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ... 
        ARIMAModel arimaModel = ARIMA.autoFit(tsVector, 1, 0, 1);
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cloudera/sparkts/models/ARIMA
at SingleSeriesARIMA.main(SingleSeriesARIMA.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:729)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cloudera.sparkts.models.ARIMA
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 10 more
```

I am using Scala version 2.11.8 and Java 1.8

Comment: If it compiled then the code is correct. - `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cloudera/sparkts/models/ARIMA` this means that the **jar** that contains that class was not present in runtime.  We can't help you if you do not explain where that jar is and how di you included in the runtime.

Comment: I see. I am using maven to build and execute the program. The dependency to sparkts package is included in  POM file. To compile, I used **mvn package**. Then, I executed **spark-submit --class "SingleSeriesARIMA" target/simple-project-1.0.jar** to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the dependency having `Arima` object present to the spark cluster using `--jars` option as below-

```scala
spark-submit --jars <path>/<to>/sparkts-0.4.1.jar --class SingleSeriesARIMA target/simple-project-1.0.jar
```

This will pass the other dependency along with the application jar to be available at `spark-runtime`.

TO call `ARIMA` object from java use-

```java
ARIMA$.MODULE$.autoFit(tsVector, 1, 0, 1);
```

Comment: It works now! I realized that I forgot to provide jar as its dependency.

Comment: Please feel free to upvote+ accept if it helps https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/767994